# how to calculate day of the month for a broad cast calendar in EXCEL

Tags: excel

can someone help me in how to calculate the day of the month in excel for a broadcast calendar. For example Jun 01 2017 should be given as 4th (previous Monday May 29th should be considered as start of the week) day of the month unlike standard calendar which shows as 1st day of the month.

Comment: so do all your months start at the monday on or before the actual start of the month?

Comment: yes , that's correct @Scott Craner

Comment: @ScottCraner any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the date in **A1**.  Then in **A2** enter:

```
=A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A1,2),7)
```

This is the first Monday in the calendar month.  In **A3** enter:

```
=IF(DAY(A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A1,2),7))=1,A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A1,2),7),A1+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(A1,2),7)-7)
```

This gives the first Monday in the broadcast month.  Finally in **A4**:

```
=A1-A3+1
```

[image]

*The **A2** formula is there only for tutorial purposes.*